# Filter redundant objects from array with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Data

```
var ranges = [
        { start: 2, end: 5 },
        { start: 8, end: 12 },
        { start: 15, end: 20 },
        { start: 9, end: 11 },
        { start: 2, end: 6 }
    ];
```

Each object represents a range. I need to remove the ranges that are contained into another.
That is, between two redundant objects I need to keep the **longer range**.

I wrote this code, but I wonder if there is a better way to achieve this using lodash.

```
var Range = {
    contains: function(r1, r2) {
        return r2.start >= r1.start && r2.end <= r1.end;
    }
};

var result = _.chain(ranges)
    .filter(function(r2) {
        return !_.some(ranges, function(r1) {
            return r1 != r2 && Range.contains(r1, r2);
        });
    })
    .value();

console.log(result);
```

Output

```
[
    { start: 8, end: 12 },
    { start: 15, end: 20 },
    { start: 2, end: 6 }
]
```

Comment: This question could be suitable for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help), as long as (a) your code works as intended, (b) your code is real code, rather than example code, and (c) your code is included in the body of the question. If you wish for a peer review to improve all aspects of your code, please post it on Code Review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a simple way to achieve this using [uniqWith](https://lodash.com/docs#uniqWith).

```
var result = _.chain(ranges)
    .orderBy(['end'], ['desc'])
    .uniqWith(function(r1, r2) {
        return Range.contains(r2, r1);
    })
    .value();
```

Comment: That's very neat. Have you done some performance checks? Big difference?

Comment: I didn't do performance tests, but I realized that only runs `Range.contains()` 8 times instead of 25.

Answer (score 2):

I really like your solution, but you can write it a bit more compact with [**_.differenceWith**](https://lodash.com/docs#differenceWith) if you would prefer:

```
var result = _.differenceWith(ranges, ranges, function(r1, r2) {
  return !_.isEqual(r1, r2) && r1.start >= r2.start && r1.end <= r2.end;
});
```

```js
var ranges = [
  { start: 2, end: 5 },
  { start: 8, end: 12 },
  { start: 15, end: 20 },
  { start: 9, end: 11 },
  { start: 2, end: 6 }
];

var result = _.differenceWith(ranges, ranges, function(r1, r2) {
  return !_.isEqual(r1, r2) && r1.start >= r2.start && r1.end <= r2.end;
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

These solutions work great when you don't have that many ranges. If you have a large array, it might be worth going with two regular while loops:

```
function between(r1, r2) {
  return r1.start >= r2.start && r1.end <= r2.end;
}

var i = ranges.length;
while(i) {
  --i;
  var r1 = ranges[i];
  var j = i;
  while(j) {
    --j;
    var r2 = ranges[j];
    if(between(r1, r2)) {
      ranges.splice(i, 1);
      break;
    } else if (between(r2, r1)) {
      ranges.splice(j, 1);
      --i;
    }
  }
}
```

```js
var ranges = [
  { start: 2, end: 5 },
  { start: 8, end: 12 },
  { start: 15, end: 20 },
  { start: 9, end: 11 },
  { start: 2, end: 6 }
];

function between(r1, r2) {
  return r1.start >= r2.start && r1.end <= r2.end;
}

var i = ranges.length;
while(i) {
  --i;
  var r1 = ranges[i];
  var j = i;
  while(j) {
    --j;
    var r2 = ranges[j];
    if(between(r1, r2)) {
      ranges.splice(i, 1);
      break;
    } else if (between(r2, r1)) {
      ranges.splice(j, 1);
      --i;
    }
  }
}

console.log(ranges);
```

Comment: Your solution is better than mine but I think it's still a bit inefficient because the comparison is performed repeating combinations which are not needed. For example ranges[0] is compared to ranges[1], and ranges[1] is compared to ranges[0] although the result will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid redundant comparisons for large datasets you could have the ranges sorted before comparing them:

```
var sorted = _.orderBy(ranges, ['start', 'end'], ['desc', 'asc']);

var result = _.chain(sorted)
    .filter(function(r2, i) {
        //Only the items after r2 may contain r2 so we slice the array.
        return !_.some(_.slice(sorted,i+1), function(r1) {
            // You could just test if r2.end <= r1.end here
            // We already know that r2.start >= r1.start
            return Range.contains(r1, r2);
        });
    })
    .value();
```

All the items before `r2` start after `r2` and can't contain it, so we don't compare them.

I don't think lodash offers any way to do this out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Could plain JavaScript (ES6) not be an option?

```
ranges = ranges
    .sort( (a,b) => a.start - b.start || b.end - a.end )
    .reduce( (acc,a,i,ranges) => a.end > acc[1] ? [acc[0].concat([a]), a.end] : acc, [[],0] )
    [0];
```

```js
var ranges = [
    { start: 2, end: 5 },
    { start: 8, end: 12 },
    { start: 15, end: 20 },
    { start: 9, end: 11 },
    { start: 2, end: 6 }
];

ranges = ranges
    .sort( (a,b) => a.start - b.start || b.end - a.end )
    .reduce( (acc,a,i,ranges) => a.end > acc[1] ? [acc[0].concat([a]), a.end] : acc, [[],0] )
    [0];

console.log(ranges);
```